# how do i change my bitcoin cleint application?

Tags: bitcoin-core, client, bitcoin-core-development, bitcore

I recently downloaded the bitcoin (--testnet) blockchain data using Bitcore(I thought it was the Orginal client) for some development purpose. but now, I like to move to bitcoin core client. Should I require to download the entire Blockchain data again?

Comment: What software? Where did you download it?

Comment: This? https://github.com/bitpay/bitcore. I doubt the block file format will be compatible between this node.js application and bitcoin-core

Comment: You might be able to get the new wallet to sync from the old wallet. It will be faster to sync over a LAN.

Comment: https://bitcore.io/ @PieterWuille